# DevExpress Real Time Chart for ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, devexpress, linechart

Is there any example for a Real Time Chart using the DexExpress in ASP.Net?

The data will come from a WCF Service.

I need to simulate a pulse rate chart, updating it every 2 seconds, I checked the demo examples for the DevExpress but I only found a Real Time Grid in ASP.Net and the charts are static.

Any help will be welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe that you could easily configure the DevExpress Chart control to do that out of the box.  You could set up an AJAX timer to refresh it every 2 seconds, which is as close as you'll probably get to what you want.

However, might I suggest using this free JavaScript based solution instead. It offers real time functionality by design: http://smoothiecharts.org/tutorial.html

Comment: I tried the Ajax timer, but the change between images is very obvious, the changes should be as imperceptible as possible.

Comment: Currently I am trying to use ChartFX solution I found an example (http://demo.softwarefx.com/chartfx/aspnet/ajaxsamples/) that is just what I was looking for but It has some problems with the options of the menu the options execute very slowly.

Comment: @richardtk_1: So glad you found a suitable control to start with.  Let me know if there is anything else I can help with.